# How to install Arch Linux to laptop Harddrive from Virtual Machine (VMWare)

Tags: wireless-networking, vmware, grub, arch-linux

I have my laptop's HD in my PC. I want to install it without any issues to work on the laptop. For example, things like assuming the wrong hardware or putting grub on my PC.

For one thing:
My PC's USB wireless adapter apparently shows up as Ethernet in the VM. I remember reading something tricky about wifi when it comes to Arch installer, and that you can mess it up. My laptop has internal wifi.

I just need the base system, and I can take it from there if it boots.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is a little vague, but from what it sounds like you have the laptop hard drive connected into your desktop and you're looking to install arch linux on this hard drive?

If so I'm going to assume you want a total OS install. You'll need to boot from an arch linux install disk (be it USB or a CD) on your PC. When going through the installer select the unmounted laptop hard drive. From there you should be good!

If you'd like something to follow there's another user in the arch linux forums [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=65844) that did something similar.